# R - Replacing missing values in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like dt below.  It's mostly complete, but has a few missing values that I'm trying to fill in a reasonable way.

```
set.seed(2015)
require(data.table)
dt<-data.table(id=1:10, x=sample(letters[1:3],10,replace=TRUE), y=sample(letters[4:6],10,replace=TRUE), key="id")
dt[sample(10,3), y:=""]
dt
    id x y
 1:  1 a f
 2:  2 c  
 3:  3 a d
 4:  4 a  
 5:  5 a f
 6:  6 b f
 7:  7 b  
 8:  8 a d
 9:  9 b f
10: 10 b e
```

For each missing y, I would like to set the y value equal to the most frequent (non blank) y value for its class in x.  In the case of a tie, choose a random y of the tied winners.  If no winner exists, leave y blank.  In this example my data table should get transformed to

```
    id x y
 1:  1 a f
 2:  2 c  
 3:  3 a d
 4:  4 a d
 5:  5 a f
 6:  6 b f
 7:  7 b f
 8:  8 a d
 9:  9 b f
10: 10 b e
```

or

```
    id x y
 1:  1 a f
 2:  2 c  
 3:  3 a d
 4:  4 a f
 5:  5 a f
 6:  6 b f
 7:  7 b f
 8:  8 a d
 9:  9 b f
10: 10 b e
```

(the y value in row 4 could become d or f)

Couldn't figure out an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first get the corresponding entries to replace `y` with for each value in `x` as follows:

```
idt = dt[, .N, by="x,y"][, list(y=sample(y[N %in% max(N)], 1L)), by=x]
#    x y
# 1: a d
# 2: c  
# 3: b f
```

and then replace missing `y` *by reference* using a binary-subset for each `x` on `idt` as follows:

```
setkey(idt, x)
dt[y == "", y := idt[x]$y]
#     id x y
#  1:  1 a f
#  2:  2 c  
#  3:  3 a d
#  4:  4 a d
#  5:  5 a f
#  6:  6 b f
#  7:  7 b f
#  8:  8 a d
#  9:  9 b f
# 10: 10 b e
```

Comment: This looks good except for one issue - if the most frequent class in x for a given y is the empty string, this appears to assign the empty string to that y.  I think I fixed this issue by idt = dt[y!="", .N, by="x,y"][, list(y=sample(y[N %in% max(N)], 1L)), by=x]  Thanks for your help, Arun.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is fastest, but you can do by:

```
dt[, z := ifelse(y!="", y, if(length(el <- sort(table(y[y!=""]), decreasing = TRUE)) > 0 ) {names(el)[1]} else {""}),by=x]
```

then you will get

```
> dt
    id x y z
 1:  1 a f f
 2:  2 c    
 3:  3 a d d
 4:  4 a   d
 5:  5 a f f
 6:  6 b f f
 7:  7 b   f
 8:  8 a d d
 9:  9 b f f
10: 10 b e e
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this handles ties in a random manner, thus introducing bias into my dataset.  For example, I think this method will always set the y value of row 4 equal to 'd' instead of possibly setting it to 'f'.